# Populating Spinner with JSON not showing anything even though there is no error

Tags: android, json

I think the problem i'm facing is because the ui draw my layout fist which is spinner before getting my data from the backend... so i need to block it and wait for my data first but i don't know how
My json data which is retrieved from the backend is like this,

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "nom": "xxxx",
        "etat": 0
    }
]
```

I'm trying to populate a spinner with data using the JSON data which I got from my backend. Even though I'm not getting any errors but still not getting the result what I'm looking for.

My class is like this,

```
// URL
String URL= AppConfig.URL_GetFolders;
Spinner spinner;
ArrayList<String> Folders;

NavigationView navigationView;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.folder_activity);
    init(savedInstanceState);

    // declaring spinner refs
    Folders=new ArrayList<>();
    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.folder_Name);

    // Spinner section

    loadSpinnerFolders(URL);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String folder =   spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),folder,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });


}
```

and my spinner function is like this,

```
 private void loadSpinnerFolders (String url) {
        RequestQueue requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String dossier = jsonObject1.getString("nom");
                            Folders.add(dossier);
                        }

                    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Folders));
                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

and my folder layout is like this,

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_activity_DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- The main content view -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/folder_Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you show the full json? because your code does this jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");.... but there is no data array

Comment: I'm sorry i just edit it out, that the json i get back

Comment: debug it. should be working. whats the size on Folders? check it after the for loop

Comment: the problem i'm facing is that the ui draw my layout fist which is spinner before getting my data from the backend... so i need to block it and waitt for my data first but i don't know how

Comment: then add a handler. ill add an answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Handler....

This will wait for 5 seconds. You can adjust it by editing the 5000.

1000 = 1 second.

```
  Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // yourMethod();
            }
        }, 5000);
```

You can also do an async task.

```
private class MethodNameHere extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //THINGS TO DO BEFORE THE CODE STARTS (create a new List)

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            //things to do because you draw the layout in post
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //draw the view
            }
    }
```

To run the async task, you do

```
new MethodNameHere.execute();
```

Also, if your spinner values dont change, dont get them from the server. Store them locally.

This is a simple way to use a List and put it into a Spinner.

```
Spinner spinner;
List<String> spinnerList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();

    spinnerList.add("test 1");
    spinnerList.add("test 2");
    spinnerList.add("test 3");
    spinnerList.add("test 4");
    spinnerList.add("test 5");

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);

    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);


}
```

onPreExecute, create a NEW list.

Now, in your case, you need to get your response, iterate through the array, and add the items to the list. Do that part in doInBackground.

In post... do this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);

spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: @brxnzaz check my update at the bottom. dont over think this. its pretty easy.